# Como utilizar quebra de linha no na variável PHP que será armazenada em uma tabela do banco de dados?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, possuo um campo em um tabela MYSQL que armazena dados e esses dados são exibidos para o usuário.

Esses dados são inseridos pelos usuários, porém, os usuários também podem acrescentar informações nesse campo da tabela e essas informações são concatenadas com as antigas (ou seja, o valor não é substituído).

Só que quando é exibo fica meio que bizarro tudo em uma linha só. Vejam a tabela e a exibição no html.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Saída na Página

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só pra deixar claro, que primeiro eu inseri o Flamengo, depois o Vasco, depois o Botafogo, depois o Palmeiras e por último o Santos.

Só que eu gostaria que cada vez que eu adicionasse dados nesse campo, os itens fossem exibido na página HTML quebrando linha. Ou seja, Cada clube ficasse em uma linha.

Já consegui dar espaço entre as informações, mas a quebra de linha é que está me quebrando.

Se for possível me ajudar, ficarei grato.

Utilizei AJAX para enviar os dados e PHP para fazer a consulta no banco Mysql.

Creio que não seja preciso adicionar o código para tal pergunta.

Espero ter sido o mais claro possível.
Obrigado!

Inseri o Código para detalhar melhor a situação.

```html
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="modal-observacoes">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header bg-success">
        <button class="close" aria-label="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Inserir Observações na Atividade</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body bg-success">

        <form id="inserir-observacoes">

          <div class="form-group col-lg-12" style="font-size: 120%">
            <label for="observacoes-modal">Observações - Máximo de 500 caracteres</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="observacoes-modal" id="observacoes-modal" style="resize: none" rows="4" maxlength="500" required></textarea>
          </div>

          <input type="text" name="codigo-modal-observacoes" id="codigo-modal-observacoes">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="enviar-modal-observacoes" id="enviar-modal-observacoes" value="Inserir">


        </form>

        <!--
                                <div id="confirmacao-inserir-informacoes">
                                    
                                    <h4></h4>
                                    
                                </div>
                                -->


      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- PARTE PHP QUE FAZ REALIZA O RECEBIMENTO DOS DADOS E EXECUTA A QUERY -->
<?PHP

 if($_POST)
        {
                        
            
            //PREENCHE AS VARIÁVEIS COM OS DADOS VINDOS DOS CAMPOS DO FORMULÁRIO
            $observacoes = !empty($_POST["observacoes-modal"]) ? " \n" . $_POST["observacoes-modal"] : null;
            $codigo  = !empty($_POST["codigo-modal-observacoes"]) ? $_POST["codigo-modal-observacoes"] : null;
            
            
            
            $pesquisar_observacoes = "UPDATE tbl_atividades SET DETALHES = CONCAT(DETALHES, '$observacoes'), DATA_DETALHES = NOW(), DETALHE_VISUALIZADO = '$resultado' WHERE codigo = $codigo"; 
            $operacao_insercao_observacoes = mysqli_query($conecta, $pesquisar_observacoes) or die("Erro no Update");   
            
     }
     
?>
```

CONSEGUI RESOLVER COM A RESPOSTA DO SAM. ADICIONEI UM 
 CONCATENADO COM O TEXTO QUE VEM DO FORM NA VARIÁVEL PHP QUE ENTRA NA QUERY DO UPDATE.

Mas agora me deparei com outro problema. Quando a coluna tem o valor 'null' no banco de dados, eu não consigo fazer a concatenação com o valor vindo do formulário.

Comment: Uma ideia seria adicionar após cada nome de time um "`_`", tipo: `Flamengo_Vasco_Botafogo_Atlético Mineiro_`, e no PHP fazer um replace do "`_`" por um `<br>`.

Comment: Creio que adicionar o código seja preciso sim. De onde você está pegando o input? É de um textarea? de um WYSIWYG? As strings contém algo como `\n` enquanto no JavaScript?

Comment: No lugar do espaço você substitui para `<br>`, exemplo: `echo str_replace(' ', '<br>', $valor_banco);` .

Comment: Você usou um `textarea` para inserir essa informação? Pois se for o caso, quando o usuário apertar o `enter` gera o `\n` automaticamente. Depois, no php, você pode usar `nl2br` ou o `str_replace` e inserir os `<br>` no texto. Quando você fizer a seleção já estará lá!

Comment: @LipESprY eu só não sei se é realmente isso! =) Mas se você tiver uma resposta em mente sobre isso, pode fazer!

Comment: @LipESprY quem falou que o comentário dele responde, isso é definido pelo autor da pergunta!

Comment: @LipESprY sim, mas, isso é o autor da pergunta decide, ele poderia entrar no comentário e dizer essa é a resposta, mas, a sua suposição pode estar errado e ai se sabe que a vida aqui não é fácil, estou só alertando e desculpa por isso.

Comment: O problema, ao meu ver, é que tem muitas soluções para esta resposta. Para chegar em algo mais próximo seria bom saber como o dado é adicionado. No caso, Flamento e Vasco estão junto!

Comment: E na verdade @AndreiCoelho é uma opção ruim como ele adiciona.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Fazer replace pelo espaço não dará certo porque se o time possuir mais de uma palavra (ex. _Atlético Mineiro_) irá inserir um `<br>` no meio do  nome do time: `Atlético<br>Mineiro`

Comment: verdade @Sam ... Por isso que eu acho que para chegar em algo mais próximo seria melhor ver como o dado é inserido! É ali que eu me refiro! E analisando o que foi dito por você agora, acredito que nenhum regex ou replace resultará em uma solução na forma como o dado está. É necessário mudar a forma como ele é inserido... Ao meu ver...

Comment: Ele poderia já colocar no banco o `<br>`, tipo: `Flamengo<br>Vasco<br>Botafogo etc.`, mas eu sugeri colocar um `_` no lugar do `<br>` porque economiza espaço no banco: `Flamengo_Vasco_Botafogo etc.`... aí é só fazer o replace: `str_replace('_', '<br>', $valor_banco);`

Comment: @Sam exato! Era essa a solução que eu me referia no primeiro comentário! Ele já inserir no banco os <br> da vida!

Comment: @LipESprY eu sei o objetivo do site, mas, isso sendo uma suposição não é resposta, é isso que eu estou dizendo. Comentário não é resposta inclusive abaixo já aconteceu outros questionamentos que eu concordo, se o cara da pergunta não diz nada é complicado saber o que ele precisa. Na verdade as informações não poderiam ser gravadas assim.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "*- Só que eu gostaria que cada vez que eu adicionasse dados nesse campo, os itens fossem exibido na página HTML quebrando linha. Ou seja, Cada clube ficasse em uma linha.*"

Uma das várias alternativas e que julguei ser bem simples, é adicionar uma quebra de linha **a cada valor adicionado** no seu banco de dados. E na hora de mostrar, já no PHP, utilizar a função `nl2br`.

Para facilitar na reprodução, vou utilizar uma *string* montada parte por parte - que **simboliza** você inserindo as partes uma a uma no seu banco de dados:

```
<?php
$str = 'Flamengo'.PHP_EOL;
$str .= 'Vasco'.PHP_EOL;
$str .= 'Botafogo'.PHP_EOL;
$str .= 'Atlético'.PHP_EOL;
$str .= 'Santos'.PHP_EOL;

echo $str;
// Mosta: Flamengo Vasco Botafogo Atlético Santos

echo nl2br($str);
/* Mostra:
Flamengo
Vasco
Botafogo
Atlético
Santos
*/
```

A constante `PHP_EOL` representa uma quebra de linha de acordo com o sistema operacional rodando o PHP. Se Windows: `\r\n`, se UNIX: `\n` e se MAC: `\r`.

> Leitura recomendada: [PHP: Constantes Pré-definidas](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.constants.php);
>
> Leitura recomendada: [PHP: nl2br](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.nl2br.php)

---

Nada te impede de colocar algum caractere entre cada valor e depois substituí-lo por uma quebra de linha HTML:

```
<?php
$str = 'Flamengo'.'+';
$str .= 'Vasco'.'+';
$str .= 'Botafogo'.'+';
$str .= 'Atlético'.'+';
$str .= 'Santos'.'+';

echo $str;
// Mosta: Flamengo+Vasco+Botafogo+Atlético+Santos+Flamengo

echo str_replace('+', '<br>', $str);
/* Mostra:
Flamengo
Vasco
Botafogo
Atlético
Santos
*/
```

Mas pensa comigo: se tem a constante `PHP_EOL` **feita para quebras de linha**, por que usar qualquer caractere para fazer o serviço dela?!

Sem falar que se você inserir algum valor **que contenha tal caractere**, ele vai ser transformado em uma quebra de linha!

---

> "*- Funciona em coluna varchar?*" - [Sam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/8063/sam)

Sim! Funciona! Veja:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN `quebra_ln`;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| valores | varchar(100) | YES  |     |         |       |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.14 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM `quebra_ln`;
+-----------------------------------------------+
| valores                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| Flamengo
Vasco
Botafogo
Atlético
Santos
 |
+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Já no PHP, pode rodar esse script para confirmar:

```
<?php
$mysql = new \PDO(...);

$valor1 = 'Flamengo'.PHP_EOL;

$mysql->query("INSERT INTO `quebra_ln` VALUES ('$valor1');");

$valor2 = 'Vasco'.PHP_EOL;
$valor3 = 'Botafogo'.PHP_EOL;
$valor4 = 'Atlético'.PHP_EOL;
$valor5 = 'Santos'.PHP_EOL;

$mysql->query("UPDATE `quebra_ln` SET `valores` = CONCAT(`valores`, '$valor2');");
$mysql->query("UPDATE `quebra_ln` SET `valores` = CONCAT(`valores`, '$valor3');");
$mysql->query("UPDATE `quebra_ln` SET `valores` = CONCAT(`valores`, '$valor4');");
$mysql->query("UPDATE `quebra_ln` SET `valores` = CONCAT(`valores`, '$valor5');");

$select = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `quebra_ln`;");

$res = $select->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo nl2br($res['valores']);
/* Mostra:
Flamengo
Vasco
Botafogo
Atlético
Santos
 */
```

---

E por último: o HTML passa as quebras de linhas normalmente ao PHP pelo `textarea` e afins.

Isso significa que, caso adicione as quebras de linha normalmente em um `textarea`, você pode armazenar no banco de dados sem adicionar o `PHP_EOL`. Logo, ao exibir estes dados, basta utilizar a função `nl2br()`.

Ahhhh, e tem mais: se você for exibir esses registros em um `textarea`, **não precisa utilizar a função `nl2br()` para quebrar as linhas**. O `textarea` já vai se encarregar de quebrar tais linhas para você:

```
echo '<textarea>';
echo $res['valores'];
echo '</textarea>';
```

[image: textarea]

<sub>(Baseado na consulta exemplificada anteriormente)</sub>

> Com a contribuição do [Andrei Coelho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/15361/andrei-coelho).

Comment: Funciona em coluna `varchar`?

Comment: @Sam O nl2br funciona porque ele apenas insere um <br> na quebra de linha. Uma string.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho saquei! Valeu!

Comment: Ficou completa a resposta! Eu só citaria a questão do textarea que a quebra já vem automática. Ele pode pegar assim:  `$text = nl2br($_POST['nomeDoCampo'])` ... Adoro o textarea ! XD

Comment: @LipESprY kkkk ficou ótimo! Parabéns!

Comment: Galera, eu não botei o código pq pela imagem eu imaginei que estava claro que era uma textarea. Erro meu. Mas sim, é uma textarea. E essa textarea é enviada via post para o php, onde uso mysqli para fazer um update no banco. Eu coloquei nomes de times apenas para ilustrar. O usuário vai poder inserir o texto que quiser. Mas claro que com o limite de caracteres que eu defini no form e no banco. E é uma boa quantidade. Agradeço a todos pela ajuda e amanhã vou tentar todas as opções válidas que vcs postaram. Hoje fiquei por umas 9 horas consecutivas programando. Saturei.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta e adicionei o código html e a parte PHP que recebe os dados e realiza a query. Ah, e Flamengo e Vasco estão juntos porque nas primeiras inserções, eu estava testando e não havia colocado o espaço. Só depois de adicionar o Vasco é que eu coloquei o espaço no código.

Comment: Galera, segui a ideia do @Sam e adicionei um <br> concatenado com os dados que vem do formulário na variável PHP que realiza o update. No campo do banco de dados o <br> aparece, mas não atrapalha tanto assim. O mais importante é o front ficar adequado para o usuário.

Comment: Mas agora me deparei com outro problema. Quando a coluna tem o valor 'null' no banco de dados, eu não consigo fazer a concatenação com o valor vindo do formulário.